# Please explain Visual Studio's Configuration Manager dialog

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Solution with multiple Projects targeting different operating systems.

The top of the Build > "Configuration Manager" dialog contains the solution's active **configuration** and **platform**. E.g. **Debug** and **x86** respectively. I would expect changing that to not change anything in the list below it. But it does, in fact, change them. But they already contain  a **configuration** and **platform**, so they should be self contained, right?

[image]

Additionally, the information there seems to be wrong. For example for Debug x86 I get both the UWP and the Android projects being built and deployed, but I only want the UWP (and Xamarin Forms project, of course) to be built. Which actually seems to be what happens, contrary to what I see in the Configuration Manager. Which indicates I don't really understand it.

Also, right-clicking on a project in Solution Explorer and setting it as startup project changes the platform automatically, and this seems to be related to the Configuration Manger, but I can't seem to find where to set which platform will be chosen for which startup project.

The bottom line is that I want to be able to set which projects will be built (and deployed) for a certain startup project.

Comment: Could you please include a screenshot? I found the narrative a bit tough to picture.

Comment: @theMayer Done.

Comment: So, all this is saying is that when you select “Build” in debug Config, all projects except the Sound.iOS project will be built. That project will be skipped.

Comment: @theMayer Except that that's wrong. When I have the UWP set as startup, the Android project doesn't build. I know that because even if I have an Interface not implemented in a class that inherits from it, I don't get an error unless the Android project is set as startup project.

Comment: Sometimes projects don't build if the compiler thinks they are already up to date. It also will build dependencies regardless of what settings you have selected.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration Manager specifies the build configuration for each project in the solution. If you open up the project properties, detailed settings come up. For example, it is quite common to exclude debug information and include optimizations in a release configuration, but do the opposite in a debug configuration.

The configuration manager DOES NOT set the project that will be run when you hit the debug button. This is totally independent of the configuration manager setting in the dropdown.

In the image below, I can use the dropdown to select which of the configurations I wish to set. I think the presence of two entries for `Debug` is a bug with VS that's been around for some time. It wouldn't matter which of the two you select, it will affect the active configuration you select the one that is active.

[Read more about how this works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2017)

**Example Project Settings**

[image: Screenshot of Project Properties]